# Given 2 positive binary integers(input as string)find their sum,without converting them to decimal and print output of the sum in binary format

Tags: integer, sum

Given 2 positive binary integers(input as string)find their sum ,without converting them to decimal and print output of the sum in binary format using C
Eg:
input: 101
010
output:111

Comment: This isn't a question. This is a task.

Answer (score 0):

Some precision is necessary according to what language and environment are you intended to use. In a general way, you can simulate one of "real life" methods.

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/194518/binary-addition-in-c